# Override Objective-C Methods in Swift File

Tags: swift, objective-c, overriding

I have some methods in Objective-C.

I created a subclass from Objective-C superclass.

Now I want to override the Objective-C superclass method in my Swift class.

My code:

```
@objc class JobBusinessTableViewCell: AdItemTableViewCell {
    
    override func commonInit() {
        super.commonInit()
    }
    
   override func updateWithAd(ads: ResponseSimpleAd) {
        super.updateWithAd(ads)
    }
}
```

Here `AdItemTableViewCell` is an Objective-C superclass.

I want to override `updateWithAd` method in Swift.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer .. But looks weird ..

Worked Code :

```
 public final override func update(with ad : ResponseSimpleAd) {
        super.update(with: ad)

}
```

I don't understand the method name change in swift .. But working as expected ...